# How to mount usb automatically by uuid instead of other?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mount

I have updated the kernel till latest version,reboot it, find that my debian can't mount usb automatically,so i installed usbmount.

```
git clone https://github.com/rbrito/usbmount
sudo apt install debhelper build-essential
cd usbmount
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b
cd  ..
sudo dpkg -i "usbmount_0.0.24_all.deb"
```

The usb `sdb` will be mounted at point such as `/media/usb0`,my old pc can mount usb automatically by uuid.
In my old pc which contains old debian:

```
sudo blkid | grep sdb
/dev/sdb: UUID="464D-5386" TYPE="vfat"
```

I can find files contained in the usb in `/media/debian/464D-5386`,how can make my upgraded debian act as same way?

Answer (score 0):

In Debian, the automount location is decided by *udisks2*, which handles mounting on behalf of desktop environments. (For example, GNOME receives information about a newly detected disk, and asks udisks2 to mount it.)

If you are not using a default desktop environment, install `udiskie` to handle automounting.